# Get Value from Power Shell Pipeline

Tags: string, powershell, pipeline

I have data coming from another command output

`testCommand` will print something like this

```
a: 1
b: test
c: an3
```

I want to grep value of the specific property `testCommand | findstr 'a'`, which prints `a: 1`.

But I want to extract the value `1`. Couldn't figure out the way! If it doesn't exist print default value `default`

Comment: Lookup how to use `-split` and use it to split on the colon. You may also want to use `Select-String` over `findstr` so that you keep everything as powershell objects.

Comment: What is `testCommand` sending down the pipeline? If it is strings there are better ways to filter, if it is objects then process as objects.

Comment: @Richard, it's string. It's not predefined PS function or anything. It's custom `bat` file is printing the data to console

Comment: @arco444, couldn't figure that `$test | Select-String 'buildDir' | what to add`

Comment: `testCommand|Select-String '^buildDir: (.*)'|ForEach-Object {$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `:` in the output with `=`, you can pipe it to [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900(v=wps.620).aspx) and get a nice hashtable instead:

```
$values = testCommand
$ValueTable = $values -replace ": ","=" |ConvertFrom-StringData
$ValueTable["a"] # this will return the value "1"
```